# Facebook Graph Api User Information

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

throught facebook graph api I'm searching for certain events, 
I'd also like to get information about user how participate those events.
Using facebook graph api I'm able to pull basic information about users - name , id and profile picture.
The issue is that i'd like to get user's age - and the problem is that I'm not creating a facebook application , but a website which pulls data from facebook using their api.
In order to get user's birthday I need a `user_birthday` permission.

I wonder if i'm able to get users' age without having this permission ? The fact those users participate a certain event matters ? 
If I must have this specific permission , how do I get it ? Remember I don't create a facebook application.

Any suggestion would be helpful, thanks in advance

Comment: To get a property like `user_birthday`, you have to create a Facebook application and have your user authenticate with it. There is no other way.

Comment: There's an option to get at least user age-range without any permission ? It seems strange that I must have a special permission in order to get this data , while there are a lot of users which thier birthday is publicly shown on thier facebook profile...

Comment: If you can trust a user to give you their Facebook user name, then yes, you can get their public information via a basic API call. You can try this on your profile by visiting https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_USENAME

Answer (score 0):

- You need permissions
- You need an app
- So change your thinking about what a Facebook "app" is. Your webpage must make some calls to facebook's *Graph* or *FQL* endpoint. You must show the standard *authorization* window or web page to your users. However, in every other way your users will see a "web page", not an "app"
- Your app can be a website-only app, ie there is no canvas page at http://apps.facebook.com/your-awesome-app
- To start, goto https://developers.facebook.com and create an "app"
- Then do some searches on google about "facebook" "user age" "authentication for websites", etc, etc...